# Low Search excerpt not rendering in Low Search Results

Tags: low-search

I'm not exactly sure why, but {low_search_excerpt} is not rendering in my search results:

```
{exp:search:results collection="careers|doctors|locations|patient-stories|services|specialties|static" status="open" limit="10" dynamic="no" paginate="both" status="open" keywords:inflect="yes" keywords:lang="en" keywords:mode="auto" keywords:loose="right" keywords:stem="yes"}

    <p>{low_search_excerpt}</p>

{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Things I've tried:

1. I've chosen an excerpt for each collection listed.
2. I went to each channel and verified that the correct field is chosen for an excerpt
3. I rebuilt the index and lexicon for each collection listed.

I appreciate any help you can offer!

UPDATE

I ran the query in the link you sent:

```
SELECT * FROM exp_extensions WHERE hook = 'channel_entries_query_result'
```

The following extensions using that hook are:

- Assets_ext
- Low_search_ext
- Ep_better_workflow_ext
- Low_reorder_ext
- Super_search_ext
- Low_alphabet_ext

This is my form code:

```
{exp:low_search:form 
    result_page="/search/doctors/"
    collection="doctors"
    form_id="doctor-ajax-filter"
}

<input type="search" name="keywords" placeholder="Search for a physician name, condition or location..." value="{low_search_keywords}">
<button type="submit" class="button button-postfix-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

... NOTE THAT I HAVE THE RESULTS TAG INSIDE THE FORM TAG. I NEEDED TO DO THIS BECAUSE OF THE WAY THE PAGE IS STRUCTURED

{/exp:low_search:form}
```

Could it be that I'm getting a conflict between Super Search and Low Search? The reason I have SS enabled is that I'm in the process of stripping it out all together and replacing it with your much awesomer search! Or, do you think it's because I have the form tag wrapping the results tag?

Comment: Can you update your post and add your Form code? Also, do you have any extensions enabled (see this: https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/low-search-variables-not-displaying-since-update-to-ee2-10-1-and-ls-4-3-1#reply_15804594)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my own question. The reason it was not working is because I was wrapping the low_search:results tag with the low_search:form tag. Apparently this causes the excerpts to break. The page in question does not require that I structure my code this way, so I can easily fix. Is this a bug, or expected functionality?

Comment: I also noticed that low_search_score does not work with the scenario I had in place. Just a side note.